# Connecting Windows Phone 8 to Sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-phone-8

As I'm not that skilled in Windows Phone 8 development I would like to discuss/ask what is **the best way to connect my Windows Phone 8 to Sql-Server Database**. I tried to search through the internet and found only few guides which didn't worked for me **Linq-to-Sql** using **WebService**. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254295/longlistselector-on-wp8-linq-to-sql-binding-issue) is where I failed.

Firstly I would like to display data - this is most important, I don't need to edit them yet. But in future it is inevitable.

If the editing would work I need to edit them directly on Sql Server to which I'm connected. I also checked [Sql Server Compact](http://erikej.blogspot.cz/2013/04/generate-windows-phone-8-local-database.html) guide but that can only work under **CE 4.0** (When exporting data from Sql Server to Sql Compact) which **doesn't support Windows Phone 8**. But even if it would work it simply copy the Sql server database to Sql Compact and doesn't work with data directly on Sql Server (which is understandable because it is Sql Server Compact).

So as I was searching deeply the only way to do that is using WebService I followed some step-by-step guides on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e39H8wWWXEo) but as I mentioned before, the problem was with [displaying data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18209239/ling-to-sql-issue-when-bind-sql-to-wp8-using-webservice) as the guide led me to using ListBox because it was for Windows Phone 7.1 and in Windows Phone 8 is only LongListSelector.

I also found question [Connect Windows Phone and Windows 8 apps to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950091/connect-windows-phone-and-windows-8-apps-to-sql-server) which was quiet helpful for me.

I think I need some step-by-step guide how-to. So I would like to ask you if there is any step-by-step guide how to connect WP8 and Sql Server? If someone would be that kind and edit my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254295/longlistselector-on-wp8-linq-to-sql-binding-issue) to make it work.

Thank you for your time reading this and answers/comments.

M.S.

Comment: AFAIK, the short answer is "there is nothing built into the framework to connect a 'phone to a sql server"; you can go via WCF, and LINQ-to-SQL can help with that - but not a direct connection API. You could of course write your own TDS reader/writer...

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you for your comment, I thought that would be the best way. This should also support Update/Insert/Delete of data on Sql Server right? May I ask you if you have a bit of free time to have quick-look on my code here?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254295/longlistselector-on-wp8-linq-to-sql-binding-issue I tried there to make WCF connection but I failed in displaying data in LongListSelector. I would appreciate that so much. Thank you again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, to achieve your goal, I would do:

1. Build a REST webservice with ASP.NET Web API (http://www.asp.net/web-api) which returns objects (those objects will be translated to json automatically). For example:

   ```
   public class MyObject 
   {
     public string Content { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Controller for it:

   ```
   public class TestController : ApiController
   {
     [HttpGet]
     public MyObject Example() {
       return new MyObject() { Content = "Hello World!" };
     }
   }
   ```
2. Use a HTTP client in your win phone project:

   ```
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://mywebservice.com");
   client.DefaultRequest.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

   using (var result = await client.GetStreamAsync("test/example"))
   {
     var serializer = new JsonSerializer(); // this is json.net serializer
     using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(result)) {
       using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
       {
         var obj = serializer.Deserialize<MyObject>(jsonReader);
         // you can access obj.Content now to get the content which was created by the webservice
         // in this example there will be "Hello World!"
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Sure you can create much more complex objects which will be (de)serialized. Just take a look at the Web API tutorials.

Within your webservice you can now access any database you want.

**Edit** If you need a more detailed answer, leave me a comment.

Comment: thank you for your answer, sorry for late responding but this is way something else that I was trying to achieve here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254295/longlistselector-on-wp8-linq-to-sql-binding-issue I have already binded everything thought but nothing displayed, would you please také a look there?

Comment: @Marek I took a look at your other post. If I have time, I will post the answer in the other questions, since it does not belong here. But I hope, I could help you answer the question you had here.