# How to connect MS SQL database in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, windows-phone-8.1, database-connection

I'm building my first WP 8.1 app and I have some troubles trying to figure out how to connect my app to an existing MS SQL database that I have already made on a server.

The problem is there are not many tutorials online showing step-by-step how to achieve this.

As I understand, you cannot directly connect to a remote SQL Database from a WP app but you have to create a service that will connect to the database and the WP app will send requests to that service and respond with the data needed.

How can I create the service and how do I integrate that service within my app?
Keep in mind that I have never worked with WP apps, nor with any sort of services before, so if you can please make it as simple and straight forward as possible I would really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid this is way too broad a question, entire books are written on the topic.

Comment: I think my question is very specific. I need a service to make a connection with my sql database and use that service within my app to get the data from my database. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly access SQL Server database from windows phone app. You will first need to add a service layer. I will mention two ways to do so - as I know as of now.

1. To use WCF service to connect to the database and using LinqToSql to get data from SQL. For this you need to create two projects in the solution. First is the service and second is your app where you will use LinqToSql to query through the service. Here are the references that will help you:

   - [Access data from SQL](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/OneCode/How-to-access-data-from-SQL-Server-database-in-Windows-Store-app) (This is for windows 8 app but the wcf
     steps will help you)
   - [WCF and LinqToSql for WP tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e39H8wWWXEo&app=desktop)
2. To build a webservice using ASP.Net Web Api. Then use Http client in your application. Reference that will help you:

   - [Connect to SQL Server using REST service and WebApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268046/connecting-windows-phone-8-to-sql-server)

Then you can use LinqToSql or EntityFramework to access or query data from the SQL server database

Hope it helps!

Comment: If you are a beginner, I personally think the first method might be easier for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I was able to create the service and add the reference to my app but for some reason there is no option to call the completed event of the method in my service. Only the async which I can't even use because there is an error "This operation is not supported in the wcf test client because it uses type system.threading.task.